# Выдает ошибку 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer на метод строки ```split```

Tags: python, строки

```
Name = "Text to testing"        
print(Name.split("T","e"))
```

Пытаюсь запустить код , а в коде откуда то ошибка связанная вообще с `int`

```
 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 4):

прочитайте про метод `split`

у этого метода может быть 0, 1 или 2 параметра

0 параметров - строка разбивается через разделитель пробел `' '`

1 параметр - строка разбирается через указанный в параметре разделитель

2 параметра - строка разбивается через указанный в параметре разделитель, но только для первых `k` частей, указанных в качество второго параметра

в вашем случае

```
Name.split("T","e")
```

второй параметр - строка, что вы хотели этим показать?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
print(re.split(r'[Te]', Name))
```

r'[Te]' - регулярное выражение (шаблон) означает: взять в качестве разделителей только те символы, которые в квадратных скобках.